# Update json attribute with a condition in jolt

Tags: json, jolt

I have a problem, I don't understand how to update an attribute with a condition in jolt. For example, I have an Object with an inner array of Items. I need to update an Item attribute if another Item attribute equals to something and to return the Object.

Input:

```
{
  "object": {
    "id": "3cf1543e-be4d-11eb-84c0-87ba01ce01e0",
    "a": "abc",
    "del_sign": false,
    "items": [
      {
        "id": "111",
        "del_sign": false
      },
      {
        "id": "222",
        "del_sign": false
      },
      {
        "id": "333",
        "del_sign": false
      }
    ],
    "b": [],
    "c": []
  }
}
```

I need:

```
{
  "object": {
    "id": "3cf1543e-be4d-11eb-84c0-87ba01ce01e0",
    "a": "abc",
    "del_sign": false,
    "items": [
      {
        "id": "111",

        // here changes to true
        "del_sign": true
      },
      {
        "id": "222",
        "del_sign": false
      },
      {
        "id": "333",
        "del_sign": false
      }
    ],
    "b": [],
    "c": []
  }
}
```

My current jolt spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "object": {
        "items": {
          "*": {
            "id": {
              "111": {
                "@2": {
                  "#true": "del_sign",
                  "$1": "&3"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two step of **shift** transformations.

Determine the related `del_sign` value within a conditional as having two arrays for `id` and `del_sign` within the same object(`items`), and properly format them within the second step such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&",
        "items": {
          "*": {
            "id": {
              "111": {
                "@(2,&1)": "&4.&3.id",
                "#true": "&4.&3.del_sign"
              },
              "*": {
                "@1": "&4.&3.&2",
                "@(2,del_sign)": "&4.&3.del_sign"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "items": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2.[#2].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Edit : If there are more attributes other than the current ones(`id`,`del_sign`), then prefer using the following code in order not to individually repeat the each key such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&",
        "items": {
          "*": {
            "id": {
              "111": {
                "@2": {
                  "#true": "&5.&2.del_sign",
                  "*": "&5.&1.&"
                }
              },
              "*": {
                "@2": "&4.&3"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "items": {
        "*": {
          "del_sign": "ONE"
        }
      }
    }
   },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "items": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2.[#2].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. But the attributes in `items` seems to be hardcoded. How to change the request to avoid it? So that when we change the json specification (add new param in `items`) there is no need to redo the jolt request.

Comment: Hi @MorkovkA , you're welcome. The main idea for the conditional depends on the need that is presented within the question as *if another Item attribute equals to something* . Eg. a chosen individual value(`111`) and the rest(`*`) are distinguished by this idea. What else do you mean to avoid hardcoding which I cannot see here.

Comment: I mean if we add to `items` a new attribute `name`. So we'll have 3 attributes in `items`: `id`, `del_sign`, `name`. Or even more new.

Comment: yes, you're right @MorkovkA . I've added the related option.